# The simplest method to count lines matching specific patterns, including '0' if line is not found?

Tags: grep, sort, uniq, wc

I have very big logs (several gigabytes per day), that can (but do not need to) contain specific lines. **I have to count the number of occurences of every one of these lines on a daily basis.**

I have a file `patterns.in`, that contains the desired lines. For example:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
ffff
```

The log files can look like this:

```
asd
dfg
aaaa
aaaa
sa
sdf
dddd
dddd
dddd
dddd
ghj
bbbb
cccc
cccc
cccc
fgg
fgh
hjk
```

The first (and perhaps most obvious approach) is to use `grep`, `sort` and `uniq` in the following way:

```
grep -f patterns.in logfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

which gives the following result:

```
   2 aaaa
   1 bbbb
   3 cccc
   4 dddd
```

It is close to what I want to achieve, but my desired result is:

```
   2 aaaa
   1 bbbb
   3 cccc
   4 dddd
   0 eeee
   0 ffff
```

So the **problem** is: how to print '0' if a line from `pattern.in` file is not matched? It needs to be done in a simplest possible way, as all I have available is the *cygwin* environment.

Comment: BTW, you might need grep's `-o` option otherwise multiple lines that, e.g., contain 'aaaa' plus other (different) data will be treated as non-unique by the `sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about feeding the pattern file back in as a data file so that each pattern finds at least one match, and then subtracting one from the final reported count for each match

```
grep -f patterns.in logfile.txt patterns.in | cut -f2 -d':' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print($1 - 1" "$2)}'
```

Comment: Seems to be working well on examples, will need to check tommorow in production, as I am not sure if I have `awk` available there.

Comment: +1, nice answer. you can use grep's `-h` or `--no-filename` option to stop grep from printing filenames.  e.g. `grep -h -o -f patterns.in logfile.txt patterns.in sort | uniq -c | awk '{print($1 - 1" "$2)}'`

Comment: It **almost** works, with one exception - `awk '{print($1 - 1" "$2)}'` prints only the first word of matched line (second field, $2). If a line has multiple words, how can I write its whole contents, that is from $2 to end of line?

Comment: @gorkypl, incorporated Craig Sander's grep -h suggestion and modified the command to work with multiple input words, here goes.  grep -h -f  patterns.in logfile.txt patterns.in  | sort | uniq -c | tr -s ' ' |awk ' {count=$1 - 1; file_name=$0; sub($1, "", file_name);print(count" "file_name)}'